# Converting a decimal array into a 2D 16bit character array in C++

Tags: visual-c++

i want to convert decimal values to 16 bit binary values. i used this code in another one.

```
      #include <iostream>
      #include <bitset>

      int main() { 
      int x = 5;

      std::bitset<8> bin_x(x);
      std::cout << bin_x;

      return 0;
      }
```

this is a code posted by a member. i want to use it in a loop and store the value of bin_x in a 16 two dimensional character array. how can it be done?
here is what iam doing

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    #include <bitset>

     int main(){

int DecimalArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5,22,555,85,18,741}; //Create an array of decimal   numbers.

const int ArrayLen = sizeof(DecimalArray)/sizeof(int); //Store the size of the Decimal Array in a constant
 //strcpy(BinaryArray[i], "0000000000000000");
char BinaryArray[ArrayLen][16]; //Create an array of the same length for binary nos.


for(int i = 0; i<ArrayLen; i++)
{

    int CurrentDec = DecimalArray[i]; //Store current Decimal number in  CurrentDec variable

    strcpy(BinaryArray[i], "0000000000000000");

std::bitset<16> bin_x(CurrentDec);
cout<< "bin"<<bin_x<< endl;
for (int j = 0; j<15; j++)
         {
 bin_x=BinaryArray[i][j];


    cout<< "b1"<< BinaryArray[i] << endl;
     }


cout<<"The Decimal numbers and their Binary Equivalents are:\n\n";
cout<<"Decimal  Binary \n\n";
}

//Output both arrays
for( i = 0; i<ArrayLen; i++){
    cout<<DecimalArray[i]<<"\t "<<BinaryArray[i]<<endl;
}

cin.get();
return 0;

      }
       but i do not get the value in BinaryArray. kindly help me with it, its very urgent. Thanks!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
           #include<iostream>

           using namespace std;

           #include <bitset>

           int main(){

           int DecimalArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5,22,555,85,18,741}; //Create an array of decimal numbers.

            const int ArrayLen = sizeof(DecimalArray)/sizeof(int); //Store the size of the Decimal Array in a constant
           //strcpy(BinaryArray[i], "0000000000000000");
           char BinaryArray[ArrayLen][17]; //Create an array of the same length for binary nos.

           int i;

           for(i = 0; i<ArrayLen; i++)
            {

           int CurrentDec = DecimalArray[i]; //Store current Decimal number in       CurrentDec variable
           int index = 1, CurrentBin = 0;
           strcpy(BinaryArray[i], "0000000000000000");

           std::bitset<16> bin_x(CurrentDec);
           cout<< "bin"<<bin_x<< endl;
           for (int j = 0; j<16; j++)
           {
            if (bin_x[15-j])
               {

                 BinaryArray[i][j] = '1';
                  }



                  cout<< "b1"<< BinaryArray[i][j]<<endl ;

                    }

                     }


               cout<<"The Decimal numbers and their Binary Equivalents are:\n\n";
               cout<<"Decimal Binary \n\n";


               //Output both arrays
               for( i = 0; i<ArrayLen; i++){
               cout<<DecimalArray[i]<<"\t "<<BinaryArray[i]<<endl;
                }



               cin.get();
               return 0;

                }
```

Comment: no, its not working. i want a 16 bit binary for the decimal values. for exmaple for 1 i need 0000000000000001 in binary array

Comment: What happens when you replace your line "bin_x = BinaryArray[i][j]" with my suggested "BinaryArray[i][j] = bin_x[j]"?

Comment: i only get '0' in BinaryArray for every iteration

Comment: OK, I updated my answer. This should work better for you. (Note that you may also want to replace bin_x[j] with bin_x[15-j] so that you don't get the binary representation written in reverse.)

Comment: How am i suppose to check that iam getting correct values in binaryarray. i think it gives the bit on the ith and jth position, it doesnot give the whole 16 bit character

Comment: One more fix: Your second dimension for BinaryArray needs to be 17 rather than 16 to hold the null termination for the string.

Comment: its not working. i get perfect values in bin_x but when i put it equal to binaryarray, the problem starts from there. problem starts after this line      cout<< "bin"<<bin_x<< endl;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14924/discussion-between-david-and-user1398405)